# Using WebSphere with CometD

Tags: websphere, cometd

Does anyone know if its possible to re-configure CometD to use the WebSphere Application Server instead of using Jetty? If so, is there much effort involved in porting it over if I've already got CometD running with Jetty?

Answer (score 1):

[CometD](http://cometd.org) runs in any Servlet 2.5 or later Servlet Container, see [here](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#java).
You did not specify the WebSphere version, but I assume it's a recent enough one.

The only CometD feature that will not work in WebSphere is the [WebSocket transport](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#java_server_transports), which is Jetty specific due to lack of standard WebSocket API (now filled by JSR 356 and supported soon in CometD 3).

Your CometD application should deploy and run with no changes in WebSphere, unless you tied yourself explicitly to Jetty APIs.

Comment: Thanks for your response Simone. I'm not sure what version of WebSphere we'll be using yet but it would be a very recent version. Have you any idea when CometD 3.0 would be available?